# Routing algorithm - getting shortest route

Tags: windows-phone-8, maps

Has anybody done anything in regards to finding shortest routes on a map? But of course only going through the pushpins and routes I've added myself to the map!

I'm thinking about: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm or [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm)

So scenario would be, I draw a series of pushpins on the map and they all have routes between them ( so polylines drawn on the map ).
When an user selects one pushpin and then another, I would like to highlight the shortest route between them - navigating only on the polylines available.

Everything is available in a DB as following model:
Route > Begin ( geocoordinate ), End ( geocoordinate ), Route ( List of geocoordinate ), Distance ( double )

So I know the route metadata, but I'm struggling on how to implement the algorithm - in reference to the user pushing the pushpins and my routes.

Comment: Who's down voting this? Better comment why, now we don't know what your problem is!

Comment: Upvoted, so you're back to 0 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the traveling Salesman algorithm.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

I implemented this to solve the problems you describe :).

Comment: I know the algortithms... it's more the approach on how to do it on win phone in reference on when the user pushes the pins.

Comment: And also, I don't know who downvoted your answer, just plain stupid they didn't leave any comment...

Comment: Ah, I see ..
These algorithms are pretty CPU intense. Maybe you could do the calculations server-side, using a WCF Service. But I have no idea what that would do to overall front-end performance :-).

Comment: Ha indeed that is maybe an angle to use! Calculate off site. But that could also be a UX poblem when the uses is not online at the moment he want's to select a route :S

Comment: Indeed.. Are offline maps available for WP 8 ? Didn't know that :). 

You could do it frontend, but try to make the Architecture pluggable. So that when testing the frontends it appears the load is too much, you can easily switch to the backend calculations.